# proof of the Reverse-delete algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, proof, proof-of-correctness

is this proof ,which is provided in the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse-delete_algorithm (at the bottom of the page) correct ?

Pseudocode

```
 1  function ReverseDelete(edges[] E)
 2    sort E in decreasing order
 3    Define an index i ← 0
 4    while i < size(E)
 5       Define edge ← E[i]
 6         delete E[i]
 7         if edge.v1 is not connected to edge.v2
 8             E[i] ← edge
 9         i ← i + 1
 10   return edges[] E
```

The proof consists of two parts. First, it is proved that the edges that remain after the algorithm is applied form a spanning tree. Second, it is proved that the spanning tree is of minimal weight.

Spanning tree

The remaining sub-graph (g) produced by the algorithm is not disconnected since the algorithm checks for that in line 7. the resualt sub-graph cannot contain a cycle since if it does then when moving along the edges we would encounter the max edge in the cycle and we would delete that edge.thus g must be a spanning tree of the main graph G.

Minimality

We show that the following proposition P is true by induction: If F is the set of edges remained at the end of the while loop, then there is some minimum spanning tree that (it's edges) are a subset of F.

Clearly P holds before the start of the while loop . since a weighted connected graph always has a minimum spanning tree and since F contains all the edges of the graph then this minimum spanning tree must be a subset of F.

Now assume P is true for some non-final edge set F and let T be a minimum spanning tree that is contained in F . we must show that after deleting edge e in the algorithm there exist some (possibly other) spanning tree T' that is a subset of F.

if the the next deleted edge e doesn't belong to T then T=T' is a subset of F and P holds. .

otherwise , if e belongs to T : first note that the algorithm only removes the edges that do not cause a disconnectedness in the F . so e does not cause a disconnectedness . But deleting e causes a disconnectedness in tree T (since it's a member of T) . assume e separates T into sub-graphs t1 and t2 . Since the whole graph is connected after deleting e then there must exists a path between t1 and t2 ( other than e ) so there must exist a cycle C in the F (before removing e) . now we must have another edge in this cycle (call it f) that is not in T but it is in F (since if all the cycle edges were in tree T then it would not be a tree anymore) . we now claim that T' = T - e + f is the minimum spanning tree that is a subset of F.

firstly we prove that T' is a spanning tree . we know by deleting an edge in a tree and adding another edge that does not cause a cycle we get another tree with the same vertices. since T was a spanning tree so T' must be a spanning tree too. since adding " f " does not cause any cycles since "e" is removed.(note that tree T contains all the vertices of the graph).

secondly we prove T' is a minimum spanning tree . we have three cases for the edges "e" and " f ". wt is the weight function.

wt( f ) < wt( e ) this is impossible since this causes the weight of tree T' to be strictly less than T . since T is the minimum spanning tree , this is simply impossible.

wt( f ) > wt( e ) this is also impossible. since then when we are going through edges in decreasing order of edge weights we must see " f " first . since we have a cycle C so removing " f " would not cause any disconnectedness in the F. so the algorithm would have removed it from F earlier . so " f " does not exist in F which is impossible( we have proved f exists in step 4 .

so wt(f) = wt(e) so T' is also a minimum spanning tree. so again P holds.
    so P holds when the while loop is done ( which is when we have seen all the edges ) and we proved at the end F becomes a spanning tree and we know F has a minimum spanning tree as its subset . so F must be the minimum spanning tree itself .

**EDIT**

**actually i have problem with paragraph "firstly we prove that T' is a spanning tree" and the part "we proved at the end F becomes a spanning tree and we know F has a minimum spanning tree as its subset . so F must be the minimum spanning tree itself**

Comment: Is there any particular part that you don't understand or don't think is true?

Comment: actually i have problem with   paragraph "firstly we prove that T' is a spanning tree"   and the part   "we proved at the end F becomes a spanning tree and we know F has a minimum spanning tree as its subset . so F must be the minimum spanning tree itself ."

Comment: It will be a lot of work for anyone to explain generally why this proof might or might not be true. You should be _very clear_ and _specific_ about what your problem is.